# What is the meaning of "funky fresh fly flava"?

Tags: meaning

In English Crime-Drama movie *Ghost Dog: The Way of the Samurai (1999*), Sonny said this words to Ray Vargo

> The rappers got names like that - Snoop Doggy Dogg, Ice Cube, Q-Tip,
>   Method Man. My favourite was always  Flavor Flav from Public Enemy. He
>   got the **funky fresh fly flava**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Funky"* (related to the musical genre, attractive, an unusual, sensual, groovy style often associated with black American culture)

*"Fresh"* (new and exciting)

*"Fly"* (cool)

*"Flava"* (*flavor*, meaning taste or style)

Note that most of the online dictionaries list many definitions for "funk", all of which are valid but don't really apply here.  *Funky* is (or at least was) generally positive when used in slang.  Also, like "cool" or "hip" (or whatever similar expression the kids are using these days), it's difficult to precisely define.

Keep in mind the movie is almost 20 years old, and these musicians, while still around, aren't quite as *cutting edge* now as they were then.  The same goes for the slang used in the movie -- if you use it today, it might just make you sound *old*.

Comment: Or wild and crazy.